# ngrx effects - problems calling/stopping effects conditionally every few seconds

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying my best to enable my ngrx effects conditionally call itself every 2 seconds in following way using timer:

```
  @Effect()
  loadSummary$ = this.actions$
  .pipe(
    
    ofType(SummaryTypes.SAVE_SUMMARY),
    
    switchMap((action:any) => (action.running ? timer(0, 2000) : NEVER)),
    
    switchMap((action: any) => {

      console.log(action); /* prints 0 (how is this possible?!) */

      return this.analyticsService.getData(action.fetchArr, action.startAndEndDate).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          /* log error */
        }),
      )
    }),
  )
```

So I am calling second switchMap after every 2 seconds. `action.running` also correctly returns true or false in first switchMap call, however, the `console.log(action)` returns 0 and similarly, `action.fetchArr` and `action.startAndDate` returns undefined.

This is because i am not able to return first `action` to second action as is. Could someone guide me to what am I doing wrong?

**What I want:**

I want my effect to call itself every 2 seconds and if `action.running` returns false then it must immediately stop. `console.log(action);` should correctly return the passed object in second `switchMap` and not 0.

**What I tried:**

Tried reading about effects from last few hours and even tried using `takeUntil` but not able to find any particular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually address your misunderstanding:
.`console.log(action); /* prints 0 (how is this possible?!) */` In the  switchMap
before this step, you are switching to the timer observable and that returns a running number. Check the type of action there. It is just not what you expect it to be.

I think this should do the trick:

```
  switchMap((action: any) =>
        (action.running ? timer(0, 2000) : NEVER)
          .pipe(map(() => action))),
      switchMap((action: any) => { // now this is actually of type 'Action'
        console.log(action);
```

Comment: Thanks. this works, I was struggling with this problem since last few days. `.pipe(map(() => action)))` this was the only piece i was missing, never thought of returning the action via map

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tried somthing like this and worked

```
  public someSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  public someObes = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someSubject
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          (value: boolean): any =>
            timer(0, 200).pipe(
              filter(() => value),
              switchMap((): any => this.someObes)
            )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(value => console.log(value));

    this.someSubject.next(true);

    setTimeout(() => this.someSubject.next(false), 3 * 1000);

    setTimeout(() => this.someSubject.next(true), 5 * 1000);

    setTimeout(() => this.someSubject.next(false), 8 * 1000);
  }
}
```

I think that you should `pipe` the `timer(0, 2000)`

Comment: Okay i understood this, only not able to get how can i conditionally enable and disable timer in this case? in my case i have `value.running` argument that I can keep track of. so, if its true then timer will keep on running and if it gives false then timer will stop. How will you fit that in this code? Also, your code is in components file but the code i wrote is running in ngrx effects file, someone needs to pass a timer stop action to effects file in that case.

Comment: NgRx Effects Works linke a the subject I wrote. I'll write the effect and update my answer. What I don't understeand is: in your code `action.running` the `running` propery is the `payload` of your `action` right? or `action.running` is an Observable?

Comment: yes its the payload and not an Observable

Comment: EDIT: Thanks ALGDB, I have already solved this question as per what is mentioned in the accepted answer here.